# Positioning the large title of a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

[image: UINavigationBar]

In the layout above, how would I adjust(indent) the position of the title so that it would line up with the contents of `UITableViewCell`s?

Answer (score 1):

It is a default behavior of your navigation bar's large title. You should not change the position of your navigation bar's title. Instead you should manage your tableview's cell and label of it so that it can align properly with title!

Comment: What if in future updates apple changes nav title position ?

Comment: It's weird that he hasn't changed. Because it's so low bottom.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the left space from large title, try this:

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.layoutMargins.left = 32
```